# Practical usage of One Time Pad?

Tags: cryptography, one-time-pad

The One Time Pad (OTP) encryption is considered as a perfect cryptography. But what are the practical usages that we have with OTP?  It would be great if someone can explain how we can practically use this algorithm with some references where it has been implemented.

Comment: See also: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42730/one-time-pad-encryption

Comment: HMAC probably owes its strength (eg. HMAC-MD5 vs MD5) to the legacy of OTP's primary mechanism.